# jQuery/javascript hide video element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible somehow in jQuery to hide specific video or source element?

```
<video id="one" autoplay width="300px" height="300px">
      <source src="media/sample3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <video id="two" autoplay width="300px" height="300px">
      <source src="media/sample.mp4" />
    </video>
```

I would like to play sample3, for example, for 1 minute, then pause sample3, hide it, show sample.mp4 and play that video.

Any suggestons?

My code which I tryed:

```
var video = $('video').get(0).pause();
  if ($('video').get(0).paused) { 
    $('video').get(0).hide();
  };
```

but the `$('video').get(0).hide();` throws `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLVideoElement> has no method 'hide'`

Comment: maybe `setInterval()` could help

Comment: make a function in which first check whether the src of the video is media/sample3.mp4.. and then change it to "media/sample.mp4".. and then make another method in which use setinterval() and pass your first function and the time after which you want to execute that function as the arguments

Comment: `get(0)` de-referenced your jQuery object, so that you have the “native” DOM object. While that has a `paused` property that you are checking for here (although you could do that with jQuery’s `prop` as well), it has no `hide` method – that is a jQuery method, not a method of native DOM elements. So in the 3rd line, you have to access the jQuery object directly, not the DOM element.

Comment: Thank you CBroe! Your solution is simple and works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var one = $('#one');
    var two = $('#two');
    play_sound(one);
    setTimeout(function(){
        pause_sound(one);
        one.hide();
        two.show();
        play_sound(two);
        setTimeout(function(){
            pause_sound(two);
        }, 180*1000);
    }, 60*1000);
});

function play_sound(var file){
    file.play();
}

function pause_sound(var file){
    file.pause();
}
```